# The AOS(Animation on scroll) is not working in next 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I Use next 13 , I wanna add AOS library in my app and us it , I installed it , and added it properly to my component, but my component doesn't show and also I don't get any error.here is my Home Page code :

```
import Hero from "../components/index/Hero"
import ItSolutions from "@/components/index/ItSolutions"
import Skills from "@/components/index/Skills"
import Script from "next/script"
import AOS from 'aos';
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';

const getData = async (type) => {
const projectId = 'q8l0xi0c'
const dataset = 'production'

const query = encodeURIComponent(`*[_type == "${type}"]`)
const url = `https://${projectId}.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/${dataset}? 
query=${query}`
const response = await fetch(url)
const data = (await response.json()).result
return data
```

}

```
const Home = async () => {
<Script>
    AOS.init();
</Script>

const members = await getData('member')
const blogs = await getData('blog')
const customers = await getData('customer')
const solutions = await getData('solution')

return (

    <div>
        <Hero />
        <ItSolutions solutions={solutions} />
        <Skills />
    </div>

)
```

}
export default Home

and I used this div for another component named Skills to apply AOS :

```
<div className="max-w-screen-xl mt-28 pt-36 px-4 pb-28 sm:px-16 md:px-8 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-2 
lg:gap-20 lg:mt-16 xl:px-20 xl:mx-auto "   data-aos="fade-up"> HI There
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I did to get it to work.
I created a new file `aos.tsx` and added this to it

```js
"use client"

import { useEffect } from 'react'
import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

export const AOSInit = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({
      easing: 'ease-out-quad',
      duration: 1000,
    });
  }, [])

  return null
}
```

And to use it, I imported `AOSInit` in my root `layout.tsx` file

```js
import { AOSInit } from './aos'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <AOSInit />
      <body>
        <main className="overflow-x-clip">
          ...
          <div className="flex-1">{children}</div>
          ...
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because The rendering is server sided in Next.Js.
Just make it client sie by adding "use client" at the first row/ Like-

```
"use client";
import Hero from "../components/index/Hero";
......
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Marking a component with `"use client"` does not prevent it from being server-side rendered. It just means it will _also_ get hydrated on the client in addition to being server-side rendered. See https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive.